# Creating a transactional result set from subscription start/end dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Problem: I have a table with subscription information such as:

Subscription ID, Interval (Monthly/Annual), Start Date, End Date

What is the best method in order to create a time series of renewals for these subscriptions until their end date in SQL (Snowflake preferred)?

I initially tried to extract the day from the date and consider the renewal date to be on that day for every month for the monthly subscriptions and same month and same day for annual subscriptions. The issue there is leap years or if a subscriber bought on 1/31/2021, then 2/31/2021 does not exist.

I also have a "dates" table at my disposal which has 1 column with dates from 1970 to 2080.

```
Example:

ID   Interval   Start Date  End Date
123  Monthly    1/30/2021   5/14/2021
456  Annual     3/24/2018   2/14/2021

Result Output:

ID:   Interval: Transaction_Date:
123   Monthly   1/30/2021
123   Monthly   2/28/2021
123   Monthly   3/30/2021
123   Monthly   4/30/2021
456   Annual    3/24/2018
456   Annual    3/24/2019
456   Annual    3/24/2020
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: tag you database correctly it can't be both

Comment: Ideal use-case for a numbers / tally table.

Comment: @stu Could you quickly explain how you would use the number/tally table to lookup the corresponding date values?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can do this with `generate_series()`

```
select s.id, g.transaction_date::date
from subscriptions s
  cross join generate_series(s.start_date, s.end_date, 
                             case 
                                 when "interval" = 'Monthly' then interval '1 month' 
                                 else interval '1 Year' 
                             end) as g(transaction_date)
order by s.id, g.transaction_date
```

However, this does not return exactly what you want as the dates following 2021-02-28 are also on the 28th. But maybe that's good enough?

```
|id  | transaction_date|
|----|-----------------|
|123 | 2021-01-30      |
|123 | 2021-02-28      |
|123 | 2021-03-28      |
|123 | 2021-04-28      |
|456 | 2018-03-24      |
|456 | 2019-03-24      |
|456 | 2020-03-24      |
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately with this, the transaction date is now reset to the 28th of every month.